# Color 'Swatches' and dye kit for Leather & Vinyl?

Tags: interior, steering-wheel, seat, leather

I would like to be able to refurbish worn out leather and vinyl interiors for a broad range of vehicles. I think the pros might use a collection of 'swatch' colors on a string to match a color and then mix dyes based on formulas associated with each particular swatch's unique color code.

I am not having luck searching the Internet because it seems most companies want to keep selling you dye for each and every repair instead of giving you the ability to mix yourself. This is inefficient & wastefulness in that I could wind up with thousands of bottles of color dies for every imaginable make and model (many of which would hardly get used). I don't want that, I want to mix and match as I go.  Can someone point me in the right direction, or tell me a generic name for the type of kit the pros use?

Just to be clear, I am not trying to fix rips and tears.  I just want to recolor worn vinyl and leather. It seems a string of swatches with associated mix/match formulas is probably the way to go. I just don't know what these kits are called which makes searching the Internet difficult.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interior Color Code Paletts for Ford. Any Overlap?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/84786/interior-color-code-paletts-for-ford-any-overlap)

Comment: @Solar Mike, thanks but it does not. The question you referenced is asking if different models of Fords share some of the same interior colors. Completely different question.

Comment: It is not the make (Ford, GM, Porsche, etc etc) but the colour information that is the subject of both questions so that is what IMHO makes it a duplicate. If others agree then you and I will soon know.

Comment: Here are a few manufacturers beginning with A: Alfa, Aston Martin, Audi, Austin, Allard, Alpina. You could do a question about leather colours for each one…